# Select from mac column where mac IN list of varchar

Tags: apache-camel, postgresql-9.3

I am using Camel to send a named parameter to a query to a Postgres database.  The named parameter in question is named `members` and is a list of stringified mac addresses, e.g. `['40:61:86:05:fd:69', '40:61:86:05:fd:69']`, which I then want to use to filter my result set.

Simplified, `where mac_column IN list_of_varchar_mac`.
Actual snippet:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    mac IN(:#in:members::macaddr);
```

However, the above works only when there is ONE item in the list of mac addresses. If there are two, I get the following error:

`operator does not exist: macaddr = character varying`

Seems simple enough, it's just an array, so I try the following instead:

```
WHERE
    mac IN(:#in:members::macaddr[]);
```

New error, `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: macaddr = macaddr[]`.

Reading the [Postgres documentation on the macaddr type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-net.html), it seems that using IN is not possible:

> The macaddr type also supports the standard relational operators (>, <=, etc.) for lexicographical ordering, and the bitwise arithmetic operators (~, & and |) for NOT, AND and OR.

I have tried the following without Camel as an intermediary and it works:

`mac = ANY('{40:61:86:05:fd:69, 40:61:86:05:fd:69}'::macaddr[]);`

However, that would require me to create a string of the list of mac addresses and I'd rather not do that.

How do I solve this using only SQL? I can't touch the database, and I'd *rather not* touch the code.

Comment: Does `where mac = any (string_to_array(:#in:members, ',')::macaddr[])` work? (assuming the values are separated with a `,`

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.3 will be [end-of-live](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) this month. You should plan your upgrade to a current version

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was clear enough. The representation of the variable is `['40:61:86:05:fd:69', '40:61:86:05:fd:69']`, e.g each mac is its own string in an array. Regarding the version, I am painfully aware but stuck in this situation.

Comment: The try `translate(:#in:members, '[]''', '{}')::macaddr[]` which will replace the square brackets with curly ones and remove any single quote. The result can then be cast to an array

Comment: Seems like the `:#in:member` syntax is disallowed without the IN Postgres keyword, which makes it hard to tell Postgres that this is indeed an array. Using functions like `string_to_array(:#in:members, ',')` either gives me that the syntax is wrong using `:#in`, removing it gives me an error that says the function string_to_array with type unknown is not possible. I'm pausing this for the moment and simply formatting my parameter as a String in the code instead, so that using ANY works.